# Is it possible to preserve the current view in the Android app?

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I was,  just now, reading a question. It had a link to some relevant information on another website. I followed the link,  which,  of course, took me out of the app and into my browser. When I'd read the article, I returned to the app. It would have been nice if the question I was reading were still there. Instead, I was returned to the feed.

<sub>Apologies if this is a dupe. This thing times out when I try to search.</sub>

Comment: Did you use the Recent Activity menu or did you re-launch the app?

Comment: Just relaunched it. In fact, this is the first I've heard of the Recent Activity menu. (I won this thing in a raffle and haven't properly experimented with it.)

Comment: This seems to be working for me now. I don't recall changing any settings; nor do I recall any updates coming in.